# Who is Hebrews 2:10 referring to?

Tags: hebrews

Hebrews 2:10 NASB

> For it was fitting for Him, for whom are all things, and through whom are all things, in bringing many sons to glory, to perfect the author of their salvation through sufferings.

Is the “Him” here referring to the Father? I was confused because in Colossians 1 the “Him” through and for whom all things are being created is referring to Christ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colossians does clearly refer to Christ as the person through whom all things are made.

> ...in him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible
> and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or
> authorities—all things were created through him and for him. (Col.
> 1:16)

And I would agree with the OP that Heb. 2:10 clearly implies that someone other than than the Son causes Christ's perfection through suffering. Otherwise, the verse would slip into the error of confusing the Father and the Son. However, since trinitarian theology was not highly developed when Hebrews was written, it may be that that the "Him" referred here is simply God, rather a specific Person of the Trinity.

**Indeed, many translators substitute ["God" for "him" in Hebrews 2:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Hebrews%202:10), possibly in an effort to avoid the very question of choosing between the Father and the Son here.**

Comment: Helpful, Dan, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The pronouns can be clarified from the larger context.

We see in v9 that Jesus was crowned with glory and honour through the suffering of death, "so that by the grace of God he might taste death for every one" (RSV). The relevant point here is "the grace of God" as making the event possible.

Then v10 can be seen as a re-wording of the same point. The "He" by whom all things exist is the "He" who is bringing many sons to glory. And that should be identified with "the grace of God" which brought Jesus to glory in the previous verse. The statement that the same "He" made the pioneer of their salvation "perfect through suffering" repeats the statement about "tasting death for everyone".

So the reference to Creation in this verse appears to apply to God as a whole.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer, but they way you have answered this (the last four or five words) is likely to bring something like a hysterical reaction from the Arians.